# JavaFx Title Bar Image comes up black all the time

Tags: java, javafx-2

After researching quite a bit of the posts and trying everything out, I am out of options on my own to do a task as simple as setting an icon on the title bar using eclipse IDE and Java FX 2.

It either comes up with the default empty window icon or comes back black. Please let me know what I am doing wrong.

Here are some of my attempts,

```
//Image ico = new Image(UI.class.getResourceAsStream("Sunset.jpg"), 16, 16,      true,true);        
//Image ico = new Image("Sunset.jpg", true);// looks inside src folder
//primaryStage.getIcons().add(new Image(UI.class.getResourceAsStream("/title.jpeg")));
//primaryStage.getIcons().add(new Image(UI.class.getResourceAsStream("title.jpeg")));

Image ico = new Image(UI.class.getResourceAsStream("Sunset.jpg"));
primaryStage.getIcons().add(ico);
```

I have tried the following with the pictures I have been using,

1. I used pictures with attributes 300x300 pixels
2. I converted pictures which were 300x300 pixels to 16x16 pixels
3. I used *.ico with both 32x32 and 16x16 pixels
4. I converted .ico into jpeg and tried as well.

Please let me know, how I can overcome this.
Thanks !

**System details:**

java.runtime.version - 1.7.0_11-b21
javafx.runtime.version - 2.2.4-b19
OS Name - MS Win XP Professional
OS Version - 5.1.2600 Service Pack 3 Build 2600
OS architecture - 32 bit
Graphics card - Intel® HD Graphics
Graphics card driver – igxpmp32.sys Version 6.14.10.5384

Comment: This may be an environmental issue. What is the version of JavaFX that your system is using? i.e. From the `start` method of your `Application` invoke `System.out.println(System.getProperty("java.runtime.version"));` and `System.out.println(System.getProperty("javafx.runtime.version"));` and edit your question to add this info.  Also list the operating system type and version that you are using and your machine's graphics card model type and driver version.

Comment: Thanks - definitely seems like an environment specific thing.  At this stage I'd advise logging a bug against the runtime project in the [JavaFX issue tracker](http://javafx-jira.kenai.com) - you can link the bug back to this post and add a link to the bug to this post.

Comment: I have the same problem. java runtime 1.7.0_21-b11, javafx runtime 2.2.21-b11. I was try with many images(ico,png,jpg) and differents sizes but only a black square appear. If any one found a solution, please let us know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following works for me:

```
Image image = new Image(<some valid image location here>);
stage.getIcons().setAll(image);
```

Here is a sample app:

```
import static javafx.application.Application.launch;
import javafx.application.*;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.image.*;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class IconApp extends Application {
  @Override public void start(Stage stage) {
    Image image = new Image(
      "http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/tooschee/misc/128/Present-icon.png"
    );
    stage.getIcons().setAll(image);

    final VBox layout = new VBox(10);
    layout.setStyle("-fx-background-color: cornsilk; -fx-padding: 10;");
    layout.getChildren().setAll(new ImageView(image));

    stage.setScene(new Scene(layout));
    stage.show();
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) { launch(args); }
}

// icon license (creative commons 3 with attribution): 
//   http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc/3.0/
// icon attribution: 
//   http://tooschee.com/portfolio?worksCategory=icons
```

And the output of the app (you can see the stage icon in the top left corner of the title bar):

[image: presenticon]

The icon also shows up in the operating system task bar:

[image: presenticonintaskbar]

Test system was Windows 7, Java 8b77.

Comment: BTW, could you achieve a black icon, passing null, as you've supposed?

Comment: No, I couldn't get a black icon to show if `UI.class.getResourceAsStream("Sunset.jpg")` was null, I just got a `NullPointerException` and the app does not start up properly - it fails hard and fast, so I don't know why the original poster is seeing a black icon.

Comment: I tried the above suggestion and I still get the same black icon :-(

Comment: Did `Present-icon.png` display in any of the system task bar, the top left of the window title bar or the Stage center OR were they all black? Please update your question with screenshot of the program output on your system which shows the black icon.

Comment: I have updated the post with the system details. Sorry, I was unable to load the picture. In the system task bar and in the top left corner of the title bar, the image is all black but I can see the image in the Stage center clearly.

Comment: I actually tried the same on a Win7 machine and it worked. Jewelsea is absolutely right.Its an OS/ hardware/ JavaFx compatibility related issue.

Answer (score 3):

The cause seems to be a potential bug in JavaFx.  If you have your system set to anything below 32-bit color you will get black boxes for your taskbar and title bar icons.  Setting your system to 32-bit color will fix it.

Comment: If you believe the behavior to be a potential bug in JavaFX, you should [file a bug report against the JavaFX runtime](https://javafx-jira.kenai.com) with environment details and reproduction steps and edit your answer to provide a link to the bug report.

Answer (score 0):

This bug can be reproduced even on Windows 7 if you put the monitor in the 16 bit operating mode:
Screen Resolution -> Advanced Settings -> Monitor (tab) -> Colors = 16 bit

Seems like the issue has been filled into the JavaFX tracker here:
https://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-28947 by Joe S. from the other answer, but I won't bet on having it fixed in JDK8.